# Can I share a PHP session with a free HTTPS service

Tags: php, http, session, ssl, https

My client wanted me to set up a free HTTPS service using Heart Internets SSL certificate. It is a valid certificate.

The way heart internet (hosting company) do this is like this:

URL: http://www.domain.com
FREE SSL: https://web000.secure-secure.co.uk/domain.com

The problem is the client is using OpenCart and relies on sessions.  This session contains active log ins and most importantly items in the users cart. These session items are stored in the standard URL,  is there a way they can be added in the secure URL as well?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Sessions work like this: every time a client loads a resource it sends the contents of a cookie on its local machine so that the PHP process knows how to locate the relevant session data on the server end of things. If every request that sends this data is not encrypted, it will be relatively trivial for a nefarious person to hijack the session ID and "take over" a user's session. If the session data needs to be protected, every resource on your site that collects the session ID needs to have its transfers encrypted.

Comment: your client should buy a ssl, they are not expensive, and users of his site will be happier.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  It was very useful.  I am going to use a POST method to send a session ID.  Thanks!

Comment: Further, the user-agent will likely pass along the session ID cookie *regardless* of whether or not the resource it loads at the time actually needs the session cookie. This means that if your session data is sensitive you likely need to encrypt transfers on the entire domain/subdomain/whatever the certificate is setup to handle. As @Dagon mentioned ... SSL/TLS certificates are not expensive. Security is not something to fool around with. Tell them to spend the money.

Comment: Finally -- quite aside from MitM session hijacking, if you aren't encrypting the transfers then anyone on the web between the client and server can view the contents of the resource you send back and forth, so a session hijack probably wouldn't even be necessary. Plain text is plain text, so if you're *ever* sending sensitive data  back and forth you should be using public key cryptography (SSL, in this case).

Comment: If the client buys a proper SSL certificate will the sessions saved on both http and https URLs?